# Scrapy Request URL going wrong

Tags: python-2.7, url, scrapy

I'm Using Scrapy to crawl a site

My problem is when I extract `url` from `href` i'm getting `%20` in the url. So, to remove that i used split and got my desired url

For Example :

> Original URL : http://www.example.com/category/%20
>
> My modified URL looks like : http://www.example.com/category/

So I'm giving my modified url to `Request` method, but still request method is taking original url not a modified url

My parse and extract methods are below

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    requests = []

    # Get Product Reviews
    for url in sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div/div[2]/h3/a/@href').extract():
        url = url.encode('utf-8').split('%')[0]
        requests.append(Request(url, callback=self.extract))

    for request in requests:
        print request.url
        yield request
        
def extract(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    requestedItem = ProductItem()
    requestedItem['name'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/h1/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
    requestedItem['description'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
    
    yield requestedItem
```

So, Please any one help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Can you paste the error that you get in scrappy?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but when i tried my original `url` in `Request` it is redirecting to default page, so i want to remove that wrong functionality, and redirect to `modified url`

Comment: There would be a space at end of modified url.

Comment: Your URL it is cleaned.  Convince yourself by `print reponse.url`, before `yield request`.
Probably you experience some other behaviour, I need more details.

Comment: @SergiuZaharie Still i'm getting same problem, check my question I have edited

Comment: It is the new modified URL printed?  You are correctly creating the new url, you might have other problem.  What do you mean by " but when i tried my original url in Request it is redirecting to default page, so i want to remove that wrong functionality, and redirect to modified url " ?

Comment: When we use `original url` in the `Request` if the domain does not have such page then domain is redirecting to it's default page, So  if i remove space in the `URL` i mean `Modified URL` It will redirect to requested page. But in my case `Request` is taking `Original URL` only.

Comment: instead of split , can u use - url = str(url).replace('%20','')
then line adding (*, allow_redirects=False)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the following answer (and the related question): [Scrapy: URL error, Program adds unnecessary characters(URL-codes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799381/scrapy-url-error-program-adds-unnecessary-charactersurl-codes/32805203#32805203)

As you can see there whitespace is added to the URL. For this you could either `normalize-space` when you select the URL or simply `strip` it before you yield the request.

That's because %20 is a single space -- which is only escaped when you will call the URL and you do not see `%20` at the end of your URL.

So instead of using

```
url = url.encode('utf-8').split('%')[0]
```

You can either

```
for url in sel.xpath('normalize-space(//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div/div[2]/h3/a/@href)').extract():
    requests.append(Request(url, callback=self.extract))
```

or

```
for url in sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div/div[2]/h3/a/@href').extract():
    requests.append(Request(url.strip(), callback=self.extract))
```